# Add-in Manager ignores my unchecking/deselecting

Tags: telerik, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins, justcode

Every time I start up Visual Studio, I get nag screens from JustCode and JustTrace. Even after going to Tools | Add-in Manager and deselecting both of them (the only two items in the list), the nag screens still display! I return to Tools | Add-in Manager and see that they are again selected - even the Startup checkbox, and the startup checkbox for JustCode doesn't even allow me to deselect it.

I don't know if this is a Visual Studio problem or a Telerik problem, but it is an irritant - how can I oust the miscreants once and for all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some digging and found this for you: http://devcomponents.com/blog/?p=653

Granted it's not the same component, but the behavior is normally universal regarding addons.

Run VS as an administrator by right clicking the VS icon and selecting "Run as Administrator". This will allow the check boxes to be unchecked and have your preferences saved.

Answer (score 4):

For JustTrace you do not have a direct option to stop checking for updates. But you can make it appear less by un-checking "Include Internal Builds when checking for updates" check-box in the auto-update dialog and press Postpone. This will make JustTrace prompt only for the major releases and service packs, which are few.

Answer (score 3):

Would you be more concrete and specify which dialogs you find annoying? Probably a screenshot would be helpful.
So far, I think that the Update dialogs are poping up at the start and if I am right you can disable them.
For JustCode you will find an options in JustCode menu > Options > General > Updates. Go there and disable Automatically check for updates setting.

Comment: I don't recollect the exact wording now (I was able to 86 them via the Control Panel | Uninstall), but they were something to the effect of "Your Just[Code,Trace] Trial has expired. Please purchase it now" and all I could do was either purchase or click "No thanks, not now" - so every time I started Visual Studio I had to click the "No thanks" for both products.